# Can PieSeries of TeeChart summarize non-signifant data into an "Other" slice?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, teechart

I have a `TPieSeries` which looks like this image when populated with data. Not very bright... Can I instruct the pie series to show the top N most significant records, and summarize the rest in another slice named "Others"? So far, the only thing I've come up with has been to set chart paging and order my data so that the top N records are shown on the first page. I'm using TeeChart Standard v2011.03.32815 VCL.
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for my offtopic comment, but... That chart looks like Sauron's eye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the OtherSlice property as shown in [Yeray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/509369/yeray)'s example [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10917&p=45970&hilit=otherslice#p45970).

Comment: Is there any special treatment for `OtherSlice` to work? For instance, should I set it at run time after the data is present in my data set? I ask this because setting the properties of it at design time has no effect on my chart

Comment: @iManBiglari this works fine for me here at design-time. You can try upgrading the TeeChart version shipped with XE2 with the free upgrade for XE2 update 4 at http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28780. If the problem persists please send us a simple example project we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here at http://www.steema.net/upload/

Comment: My mistake. It works as described in by Yeray. Now, I have another question... Is it possible to instruct the series to show top N rows? For instance, if I don't know the nature of the data, I can't guess if 10 percent produces a better looking pie or 5 percent.

Comment: @iManBiglari I'm afraid not but you could implement that functionality pre-processing your data before populating the pie and then set OtherSlice accordingly.

Comment: That's what I do: Preprocess the data.